# copy database from android room to file

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-jetpack-compose

I want to copy my sqlite db for backup from `"/data/data/" + c.getPackageName() + "/databases/" + DATABASE_NAME;` to any where user wants for backup in java+xml mode and isn't any problem for restore this.,
but when I use room + compose. when copy db, isn't any problem but can't restore this (copy from backup to  `"/data/data/"....`  and when open db, this deleted.

I think that we maybe must force close room db before restoring db.
my copy function class is :

```
InputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(from);
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(to);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
myOutput.flush();
myOutput.close();
myInput.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Room uses WAL (write-ahead logging). Changes to the database are written to the wal file (database file name suffixed with -wal, the WAL file is likewise writen to the -shm file (not so important)).

If you copy the database file only and the -wal file exists and is not empty, then part of the database is not being copied. This can lead to the open considering that the database is corrupt, the file is then deleted and a brand new database is created.

That is the likely issue.

Their are 3 ways around this,

1. Ensure that the database has been fully checkpointed (everything in the -wal file has been applied), closing the database prior to backing up should fully checkpoint the database.
2. to use Journal mode logging by using the

[SupportSQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase)'s [disableWriteAheadLogging](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Callback#onOpen(androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase)) method (the journal file is a record of the changes that have been applied to the database). You would likely use this method in the [onOpen](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Callback#onOpen(androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase)) callback and probably the onCreate callback as well.

3. Backup and restore the -wal and -shm files as well as the main database.

You may wish to have a read of https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html

**Additional**

Although a Kotlin solution and that it copies the files to the databases directory, you may wish to have a look at the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73197105/how-to-export-room-database-as-a-db-to-download-file-so-i-can-use-it-later/73201175#73201175) that handles WAL (or Journal mode) aspect.